# How to get value from particaular link using js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am retrieving data from database using php:

```
<?php
while($trackResultRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trackResult)){?>

  <a onclick="remove()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down pull-right"></span></a>
    <li>
     <a href="<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_path']?>">
       <span id="username"><?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?></span> -
       <span id="track"><?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?></span>
     </a>
    </li>
   <hr>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Now when I click on the link it should take value and pss it to Jquery function (.ajax) to delete record from the table without refreshing a page.

```
 function remove()
{
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var track = document.getElementById("track").value;
  //window.some_variable = '<?=$_GET[user]?>';
  if(username && track)
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      type:'post',
      url: 'delete_proc_admin.php',
      data: 
      {
         user_name:username,
         user_track:track
      },
      success: function (response) 
      {
       return alert (username +" "+ track);

      }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```

But JQuery function does not work.

I suppose that it is because of same ids, but I do not now how to fix my code.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Your IDs are not similiar they are the same, IDs must be unique https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: can you offer a solution?

Comment: Remove the IDs in the auto generated code and use an `event` argument passed to the `remove` function or use `this` to get the target element.

Answer (score 0):

1. fix the invalid HTML
2. use jQuery for the link too
3. use data attributes

```js
$(function() { // page load
  $(".rem").on("click", function(e) { // the remove link
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    var $link = $(this), // save for later
      username = $(this).data("username"), 
      track = $(this).data("track");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'delete_proc_admin.php',
      data: {
        user_name: username,
        user_track: track
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $link.closest('li').remove();

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" class="rem" 
   data-userid="<?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?>" 
   data-track="<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down pull-right"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_path']?>">
    <span><?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?></span> -
    <span><?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?></span>
  </a>
  <hr/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass link itself to function

```
<a onclick="remove(this)"></a>
```

```
function remove(link){
  var username = link.getElementById("username");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your username and track right into the remove function and create a dynamic unique id to select the container using username and track

```
<div id="<?php echo $trackResultRow['username'] . $trackResultRow['track_name'] ?>">
    <a onclick="remove('<?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?>', 
                       '<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?>')">
```

Then in your remove function

```
function remove(username, track)
{
  //window.some_variable = '<?=$_GET[user]?>';
  if(username && track)
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      type:'post',
      url: 'delete_proc_admin.php',
      data: 
      {
         user_name:username,
         user_track:track
      },
      success: function (response) 
      {
       $('#'+username+track).remove();
       return alert (username +" "+ track);

      }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```